# Can't get ngx-bootstrap radio to work, No value accessor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ngx-bootstrap

This has been driving me up the wall.  I am pretty much using the example from the ngx-bootstrap manual here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/buttons#radio-reactiveforms and it is not working.  Here are my template and component:

Template:

```
<pre class="card card-block card-header">{{ myForm.value | json }}</pre>
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group" btnRadioGroup formControlName="radio">
      <label btnRadio="A" class="btn btn-primary">A</label>
      <label btnRadio="B" class="btn btn-primary">B</label>
      <label btnRadio="C" class="btn btn-primary">C</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-buttons-radio-reactiveforms',
  templateUrl: './keyed-payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./keyed-payment.component.scss']
})
export class KeyedPaymentComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      radio: 'C'
    });
  }
}
```

In addition I have also added the following to my app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and in the imports array:

```
imports: [
   ....
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
   ....
],
```

This is the error that i get:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'radio'
>       at _throwError (forms.js:2432)
>       at setUpControl (forms.js:2302)
>       at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:6658)
>       at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:7308)
>       at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7221)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12365)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you declared the `btnRadioGroup` in the `declarations` array on your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Which version of ngx-bootstrap are you using? `btnRadioGroup ` was added in one of the latest releases.

Comment: @ArjunPanicker No I haven't, can you show me what the import statement would look like for that?

Comment: @IlyaSurmay this is what is in my package.json file: "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2"  if that is to be believed.

Comment: @ArjunPanicker  Thanks for the tip, that's what led me to the answer.  I grepped the codebase for 'btnRadioGroup' and found it in my node-modules, then examined the files/folders where it existed and discovered the ButtonsModule export.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured it out.  All I had to do was add this to my app.module.ts at the top:

```
import { ButtonsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

and this in my Imports:

```
imports: [
    ....
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ButtonsModule,
    ....
]
```

Comment: I am facing something similar. What you meant by add this to the top? You meant to say that `ButtonsModule` has to be in `imports` or in any specific order?

Comment: Hard for me to tell what i meant because this post is over 2 years old and i'm not working in Angular anymore.  That said, i suspect the import statement should be at the top of the file somewhere and also within the imports array.  I don't think the order matters that much, but i could be wrong.